# angular cannot match routes

Tags: html, angular, href, routerlink

I want to create a menu in a angular application with rounterlinks.
My routerlinks looks so:

```
          <li>
            <a routerLink="/overview" [queryParams]="{categorie:'Shopping',subcategorie:'topcategorie'}">
              Shopping</a>
          </li>
```

If I click on the button I get the following error.

```
core.js:6241 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'overview'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'overview'
    at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.js:4389)
    at CatchSubscriber.selector (router.js:4353)
    at CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:29)
    at MapSubscriber._error (Subscriber.js:75)
    at MapSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:55)
    at MapSubscriber._error (Subscriber.js:75)
    at MapSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:55)
    at MapSubscriber._error (Subscriber.js:75)
    at MapSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:55)
    at ThrowIfEmptySubscriber._error (Subscriber.js:75)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:798)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:750)
    at zone-evergreen.js:860
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:41634)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:398)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:167)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:569)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone-evergreen.js:484)
    at invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:1621)
```

My router definitions are these:

```
const routes: Routes = [

  { path: 'overview/:categorie/:subcategorie', component: OverviewComponent },
  { path: 'overview/:brand', component: OverviewComponent },
  { path: 'overview/:product', component: OverviewComponent },
  { path: 'coupons', component: CouponComponent },
  { path: 'impressum', component: ImpressumComponent },
  { path: 'datenschutz', component: DatenschutzComponent },
  { path: 'details/:id', component: ProductDetailsComponent },
  { path: 'home', component: LandingpageComponent },
  { path: '', component: LandingpageComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Has anyone an idea why I get this error ?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're setting queryParams instead of using the routes you have set up. Link to `routerLink="/overview/shopping/topcategorie"` (if you want `/overview` to work `{ path: 'overview', component: StackOverflowComponent }` (or do a redirect to a default category/brand/product route

(the a tag now links to `overview?categorie=Shopping&subcategorie=topcategorie`)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/overview', 'Shopping', 'topcategorie']">Shopping</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
<a [routerLink]="['overview', 'Shopping', 'topcategorie']">
   Shopping
</a>
```

or

```
<a routerLink="overview/Shopping/topcategorie">
   Shopping
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the App routing module you haven't declared a route that is matching to your requirement. You have declared path variable in your routing module

```
  { path: 'overview/:categorie/:subcategorie', component: OverviewComponent },
  { path: 'overview/:brand', component: OverviewComponent },
  { path: 'overview/:product', component: OverviewComponent },
```

But you are trying for query params in the HTML.

```
<a routerLink="/overview" [queryParams]="{categorie:'Shopping',subcategorie:'topcategorie'}">
              Shopping</a>
```

Try using the below implementation.

in .ts

```
{ path: 'overview', component: OverviewComponent },
```

in .HTML

```
 <a [routerLink]="/overview" [queryParams]="{categorie:'Shopping',subcategorie:'topcategorie'}">
                  Shopping</a>
```

The resultant URL will be

```
overview?categorie=Shopping&subcategorie=topcategorie
```

The above is a query params.